# Android SSH : Convert PuttyGen PPK to Dropbear Key

Tags: android, ssh, key, putty

I am developing an Android application that utilizes RSYNC over SSH to sync up with a network folder. but im having problem with Key provided by puttygen ssh: string too long. I figured out that the ssh client installed in my device is a dropbear ssh client. For this to work, I have to convert PuttyGen PPK to a dropbear key.

Is there's a way to convert PuttyGen PPK to Dropbear Key?

Can I convert it using my ubuntu machine? so that i will just copy the generated key to my android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the dropbear source to your machine, build it, and you should have access to `dropbearconvert` which can convert keys formatted for OpenSSH to the dropbear format.

Just doing a `apt-get install dropbear` will not install the `dropbearconvert` tool.

**Edit:**
Oh, and you can convert your PPK file to OpenSSH using `puttygen.exe`.

*File menu* -> Load your PPK file.
*Conversions menu* -> Export as OpenSSH file.

Comment: Thanks man. that helped. i thought i installed wrongly dropbear in my ubuntu because i cant find drobearconvert.

Comment: Yes. It is not secure, so they moved it to: /usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I converted my PuTTY keys to work in SSHDroid:

1. Open your PPK file in **PuTTYgen**
2. **Clear the passphrase fields** as dropbearconvert doesn't support encrypted keys
3. **Conversions** -> **Export OpenSSH** -> Save as **YourKey.id_dsa** or **YourKey.id_rsa** depending on if your keys are DSA or RSA
4. Install [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) and start the server using password authentication
5. Open an SSH session to your Android device and login using the password you set
6. Transfer your **YourKey.id_?sa** file to your Android device *(any way you like)*
7. **CD** to where your uploaded OpenSSH key file is
8. Enter command: **dropbearconvert openssh dropbear YourKey.id_?sa YourKey.dropbear**
9. Import this file into SSHDroid's key management
10. **Switch off password authentication!**

The resulting file was one I could import into SSHDroid. If you want to keep the converted file for future use put it inside an encrypted 7z or RAR as this dropbear key pair file is **not protected**. You can delete the file once it's imported into SSHDroid anyway.

Comment: sadly this method tells me that my key don't have openssh header

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is installed by default, just in a weird place.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dropbear/+bug/1009868